# start at certain point in e2e test using Detox in react native

Tags: react-native, e2e-testing, detox

I am writing a e2e test to a react native app(-v : 0.63.4) using Detox (-v : 18.2.2)
the app contains several screens and I want to start at certain point in the test while I am writing it just to spare time by writing the test and not start every time from the beginning because I run the test while I am writing it to check if everything like I want it to be
I know it is called e2e test but is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: I should mention I'm using Jest as a test-runner, I don't know if you're using Jest, but I'll leave this here for now anyway.*

The way I'm doing it in my project now is to use the `.only` function on my tests.
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#testonlyname-fn-timeout

```
test.only('the user can continue to account creation', async () => {
  await element(by.id('continueButton')).tap()
  await expect(element(by.id('accountCreationScreen'))).toBeVisible()
})
```

Notice though, that in my case I have to keep the tests that logs a user in to the app. But that's fine for me, I still skip all the other tests.
Hope that works out for you, or helps in some way.